# Change TEXMFHOME per-user

Tags: texmf

I would like to know if it's possible to change the default `TEXMFHOME` location.  Partly because I dislike the idea of programs cluttering my home directory with non-hidden files or directories (such as `~/texmf/`) and partly because I would like to be able to manually install new LaTeX packages wherever I like, for example in

```
/software/local-foo/
/software/local-bar/
```

I know I could change the `TEXMFHOME` environment variable, but is there also a per-user config file which could change where LaTeX & friends look for files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not clear from the question whether you have admin access to the master `texmf.cnf` file. If you do, then this is easier than if you do not!

### Admin access available

In the case where for example you have a single-user machine and so write access to `texmf.cnf` in the installation directory, this is doable with no variable setting. You can find where this is using `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`: I see

```
palladium:~ joseph$ kpsewhich texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf
```

You can then edit this file (with `sudo` if needed) and alter the `TEXMFHOME` line to point to where you want.

### Admin access not available

The more common case, I think, if wanting to set things here is when you do not have admin access which is exactly why you want to set on a per user basis. Here, it seems you have to set at least one variable. There are two approaches.

The first is to set `TEXMFHOME` directly. This is clearly pretty easy, and is the recommended method unless you need to do more complex things.

The second approach is to set your system up to use a per user `texmf.cnf` file. This can go in a location of your choosing, but you will need to set the `TEXMFCNF` variable with something like

```
export TEXMFCNF=~/.texmf-config/web2c:
```

where the `:` is important as it makes this an additive change. You can then create a `texmf.cnf` file in this new location, and add whatever settings you want there (`TEXMFHOME` is just one possible). There is more detail on this in http://people.debian.org/~preining/TeX/TeX-on-Debian/ch2.html#s-sec-user-config-files.

Comment: How can I point the TEXMFHOME variable to two texmf folders? I came from miktex and was able to keep the default while adding a personal folder (same structure) as root.

Comment: @Anh You can have more than one location in the variable: separate them by colons (as is done for example in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree).

Comment: Is this still a valid solution after a couple of years?  The file `web2c/texmf.cnf` has a warning sign to not edit the file directly, and instead referring to `texmf.d` to make changes.  However, this file is blank and it's not clear what to change there.

Comment: @Diego You should have two `texmf.cnf` files: for me `kpsewhich --all texmf.cnf` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf.cnf` and `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`. The latter is the 'do no edit' one: you ca though add lines to the former to override.

Answer (score 1):

Following Joseph Wright solution above, without touching any "do not edit!" file, you could:

1. Locate your `texmf` directory (on Ubuntu should be `/etc/texmf`)
2. Navigate to the `texmf.d` subdirectory
3. Edit (possibly with `sudo`) the `.cnf` file (again, on Ubuntu should be `00debian.cnf`) adding a new line:

   TEXMFHOME=/your/new/path

Please note that you can use local variables, so if you want each user to hold their texmfhome under their home, you could type:

```
TEXMFHOME=$HOME/.texmf
```

4. Save the file and run `sudo update-texmf`

You can now check that the variable is update with

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

*edited to reflect the remarks by StrongBad (thank you)

Comment: Don't do `/home/$USER/` instead do `$HOME`.

Comment: @StrongBad thank you, edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

With Unix, a symbolic link can help.  For example, on my system, `TEXMFHOME` is set to `/home/alba/texmf`.

```
% kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
/home/alba/texmf
```

To use `/home/alba/Library/program/texmf` instead:

```
% ln -s /home/alba/Library/program/texmf /home/alba

% ls -l /home/alba/texmf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 alba alba 32 30 déc.  15:29 /home/alba/texmf -> /home/alba/Library/program/texmf
```

The link does not depend on shell environment, does not require admin access and can't be broken by software update.