# Update package of TeX Live 2009

Tags: packages, texlive, ubuntu

I have a CLSI (LaTeX server) instance running on Ubuntu 10.04:

http://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/

Now I want to install a new package and also upgrade an existing package. The packages contain only `.cls` (class) and `.sty` (style) files, thus I added a new folder in `texmf-live/tex/latex`, copied the new files there while updating the files in the existing folders with new files. Restarted box.

But the new package is not being recognized! :(

I tried `texhash` but it did not work. There is no `tlmgr` in the instance installed in CLSI package (from above link). Anyone has an idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Forget about TL2009; instead [update to TeXLive 2012](http://askubuntu.com/q/163682/62688).

Comment: I don't think this question should be downvoted: It is on-topic and clearly states the problem. Please don't downvote without leaving an explanation.

Comment: I suspect the down vote might have been form a new user not know what they are doing. And, [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Unless you have some legacy documents that you are afraid might have issues with new versions, I don't see a reason to stick with TL2009.

Comment: @Jake: IMNSHO this question (how to add new packages to a TL installation) is [clearly answered in the TL documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.6).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Perhaps, but in that case leaving a comment pointing the user to the relevant part of the documentation and asking if that solves the problem would be more appropriate than anonymously downvoting a new user. We answer plenty of questions here that technically would be clearly answered in the documentation.

Comment: Your 'local' tree is not one that will be searched. If you want a local tree, it must mimic the structure of the system tree.  Try changing the local tree to: `~/texmf/tex/latex/`.  I would probably add a 'csli' directory: `~/texmf/tex/latex/csli/` and put your class and style files there.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, replies & up votes :) seeing the down votes i thought this wouldnt be replied. Now CLSI im using has a custom directory structure. it puts all latex related files into /clsi/chroot
how do i upgrade in such a case? if i do regular install the files would go into default folders right?
Do i just do a regular upgrade like Jonas has said and just symlink the /clsi/chroot to latex root? And i dont have a tlmgr. How would it help if i change local tree?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree

Comment: LaTeX packages are often dependent on other packages. For instance, `siunitx` depends on the `l3kernel` suite of packages and updating it requires updating also those. If your goal is to install/update a package that doesn't depend on others, then the `~/texmf` road can safely be followed.

Answer (score 4):

**If you dont have a good reason to stay at TeX Live 2009 it is the best to upgrade.**

I have just installed TeXLive2012 on debian linux stable because i had 2009 too. It works like a charm.

```
mkdir texlive
cd texlive
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
sudo -s
perl install-tl-*/install-tl -gui

3 GB download... wait... 
Add the new TeXLive to your `PATH`
Ready.
```

You find more details on the [ctan documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html) but it is not very nice to read.

- Dont forget to adjust the `PATH` environment
- You can install TeXLive where you want. (although it is a good habbit to put it to /usr/local)
- It is no problem, if you have an older or another TeX installation on your system as it will be ignored.

Comment: i did the same, but then i've total control of my machine (being as i'm a sort of sysadmin).  your comments should be prefaced with "if you've enough spare disc space, and if you've useful control over your system.  (i _can't_ install 3gbytes in my home directory, for example -- i keep my quota lower than that, to avoid problems.)