# add texmf tree to TeX Live

Tags: texlive, paths, linux, texmf

I'm new to TeX Live.  I know in MiKTeX it's very easy to add multiple paths using "MiKTeX Settings". But how can I do this in TeX Live?

The directory I want to add is

```
/usr/share/R/share/texmf
```

It's created by the R application, so I don't want to move it.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree.  Also, [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Changing the path of texmfhome as suggested in the question you linked to is not the same. In miktex you can *add* new roots. This is not so easy in TeXLive as scripts could assume that variables like texmfhome points to *one* texmf tree and so you could run into troubles if you put a *list* of trees in the variable. So you can only *replace* trees.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer I am still searching for a solution to **add** an additional folder to texlive. Is there a solution already?

Comment: @MoritzH. yes there is, see the documentation of tlmgr. But I would really prefer if you would ask a real new question instead of pinging me personally by highjacking some old comment of mine.