# cls file - multiple files

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am writing a .cls file so that I can maintain consistency across many documents. The cls file is soooo long, and I would like to split it up into parts, in a similar fashion that one does when writing a document. Can I do this, the `\input{...}` command doesn't seem to recognize a sub-folder of the parent .cls file in my TEXMFHOME tree structure.

Comment: What are you calling the subfiles? The directory structure for TeX files requires that they are in the 'right' place in order to find them, and that depends on the extension used.

Comment: when the .cls file is a single file, and put into `./home/<user>/texmf/latex/MYCLASS/myclass.cls`, it works fine, however, not if `myclass.cls` refers to files in `./home/<user>/texmf/latex/MYCLASS/SUBFILES/`

Comment: What extension should be used...?

Comment: Please consider to look for appropriate existing tags before creating new ones.

Comment: I changed the extenstion to .sty, ran texhash and it worked fine. Not sure if that is the right thing to do.

Comment: @ADP Not unless it's a package. I'd use either `.tex` or `.def` here.

Comment: Didn't realize that I created a new tag, I just typed it in and the form accepted it.

Comment: OK, I'll write up an answer in a few minutes :-)

Comment: Ok. I'll tick your answer a few minutes after a few minutes :-)

Comment: @ADP Having done some tests on my system, there is a bit more to this. What TeX system do you have, and what extension(s) did you try that failed?

Comment: .tex failed. .def and .sty worked, but in alignment with your advice on not using .sty, I have gone with .def. 

Also, .def needed to be in same directory as the .cls file, to use \input{XXX.def} in the .cls file and having it recognised by texstudio (for convenience).

My system Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I use texstudio, and generally compile with LuaLatex.

Comment: I am sure your long class file has some functionalities you can outsource in a package, for example your standard macros. Advantage: your class is not so long and you can use this small package in every `tex` file you want with `\usepackage{my-macros}` if you call it `my-macros.sty`. In your class you need to write `\RequirePackage{my-macros}`.

Comment: I think it is better to mimic the `texmf` directory structure more precisely.  I'd use `~/texmf/tex/latex` for things LaTeX-related. The fact that you had to run `texhash` suggests to me that `Kpathsea` is not searching `~/texmf/latex` on its own initiative, as it would `~/texmf/tex/latex`. (But I haven't really looked into this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write a new/own class use a local directory to develop it. Inside the directory you write a file `myclass.cls` to be called as document class in a test document in the same directory. Think over the functionality of your class and outsource logical units into packages like file `mypackage.sty` (in the same directory). Now you can load this package with `\RequirePackage{mypackage}` in your class.  The advantage of outsourcing functionality to packages is that you can use them in other classes or—if needed—in other documents (`\usepackage{mypackage}`) without loading the own class.

After you finished development of your class, create a new directory in your local TeXMF tree, copy all `.cls` and `.sty` to it. If you do not know how to create and use a local TeXMF please see the questions [create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) and/or [how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree).

To learn more about writing classes read the `clsguide` (`texdoc clsguide`).

A class or a package is never loaded with `\input{...}` as it seems you are trying to do.