# Create a local texmf tree in Ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, linux, texmf

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 which came with TeX Live 2009 pre-installed.
I want to create a local texmf tree at the location `~/Dropbox/mylocaltexmf/`,
so that I can place my own `.sty` files in my Dropbox which automatically syncs across multiple computers.
How do I make a local texmf tree visible to TeX Live?
**Note that I do not want to place the `.sty` files in the default TEXMFHOME.**

Similar questions but on different operating systems:

- **Windows** [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)
- **Mac OS X** [How to make LaTeX see local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree)

I tried to follow the solution in [How to make LaTeX see local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree),
but when I ran the command `tlmgr` it seems that there is no such command on my system.

```
$ tlmgr
No command 'tlmgr' found, did you mean:
 Command 'vlmgr' from package 'qdbm-util' (universe)
 Command 'rlmgr' from package 'qdbm-util' (universe)
tlmgr: command not found
```

Comment: You need to [install "vanilla" TeX Live](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why is `~/mylocaltexmf` going to be better than `~/texmf` (= normal `TEXMFHOME`)?  But, anyway, look in `texmf.cnf` for these settings.  Or install TeX Live from TUG, as suggested.  Or use symlinks.

Comment: See my edit. The real folder I want to be my local texmf tree at is actually a folder in my Dropbox which can sync across multiple computers.

Comment: OK.  Find your `texmf.cnf`, namely the one you should/can edit.  Since you are using the Debian-based TeX Live, I'm not sure where that is.  Try to find it with `kpsewhich` or `locate`.  The one you should edit says it should contain (only) your personal changes.  Add this line: `TEXMFHOME = ~/Dropbox/texmf` (or `mylocaltexmf`).  Now -- important! -- do `mkdir ~/Dropbox/texmf/tex/latex` and put your `.sty` files there. `TEXMF*` folders must mimic the TeX Live Directory Structure (TDS). Thus a `.bib` file should go in `~/Dropbox/texmf/bibtex/bib`; etc., etc.

Comment: With just one local texmf tree, you can use these commands: `cd; mv texmf texmf.orig; ln -s ~/Dropbox/mylocaltexmf/ ~/texmf`

Comment: Paul, your solution works. Do you want to submit it as an answer which I can accept?

Comment: jon, `locate texmf.cnf` returns two files `/etc/texmf/texmf.cnf` and
`/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`, both of which contain the contents:
`This file is automatically generated by update-texmf
PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY. It is meant to be generated from 
files in /etc/texmf/texmf.d/.`
Perhaps as Adam said I need to install a vanilla version of TeX Live.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, paging to submit answer and collect reputation.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, you need to tell tex to look in your `~/Dropbox/mylocaltexmf` folder as the user `texmf`, instead of in the default, `~/texmf`. To do this, you need to create the file `10localtexmf.cnf` (or some similarly named file) in `/etc/texmf/texmf.d`, and tell it your custom value of your home `texmf`:

`cd /etc/texmf/texmf.d
sudo touch 10localtexmf.cnf
sudo echo "TEXMFHOME = ~/Dropbox/mylocaltexmf" > 10localtexmf.cnf`

Next, you need to tell Ubuntu to generate the `texmf.cnf` file in `/etc/texmf/web2c` from the contents of the `/etc/texmf/texmf.d` directory:

`sudo update-texmf`

Great! Now test to see whether this has worked by running:

`kpsexpand \$TEXMFHOME`

If that outputs `~/Dropbox/mylocaltexmf`, then it's worked, and you're set. If it outputs `~/texmf`, it means it's still set on the default. If this is the case, check the contents of `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` to check whether `update-texmf` has successfully appended your custom `TEXMFHOME`.

I personally use this to sync my custom `beamer` themes. Oh, and remember that as [jon said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161001/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-ubuntu#comment368585_161001), the contents of your `localtexmf` must mirror the standard `texmf` structure, so custom `latex` styles and themes should be put in `~/Dropbox/mylocaltexmf/tex/latex`. Also, remember to run `sudo texhash` whenever you update your local `texmf`.

Comment: Ran through this, and it did not work for me. Even though /etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf says TEXMFHOME = /home/*STUFF*/Dropbox/texmf, kpsexpand \$TEXMFHOME only outputs /home/*STUFF*/Dropbox, no texmf at the end.

Comment: @drewsberry: I have made `mylocaltexmf` in `~/path/to/mylocaltexmf`. Inside that, I have created the folder `tex/latex` and have copied the `verse` folder which contains `verse.sty` into it. But when I run a sample `test.tex` file, I get the error `verse.sty` not found. `sudo texhash` doesn't seem to indicate `mylocaltexmf`. `kpsexpand` command doesn't exist in my system. But `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` has an entry for `mylocaltexmf`. And finally, the `test.log` doesn't show any entry of searching the `verse.sty` in `mylocaltexmf`. What am I doing wrong?