# Is it possible to store CTAN packages locally next to the *.tex file?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, ctan

For archiving purposes, it would be good to not depend fully on the online distributions of different usepackages. I wonder if it's possible to store them locally and possibly also load compile documents directly from their local folder?

Ideally, I would like to save everything needed to compile a *.tex document within one folder that's version controlled by Git and then be able to run TexMaker / MikTex and compile that document on another computer without having to redownload usepackages externaly into that computer.

This would be useful to make sure that you keep the specific versions of the usepackages you use, even if they would get lost or updated in a way not compatible with your document. Yes, I know that usepackage history in many cases is available on CTAN, but if this could be done easily that would make the archive more safe.

Also, this could possibly make it easier to share complete documents when collaborating over git.

Would appreciate any direction, either towards existing solutions or towards how to create a solution.

Comment: One relatable thread I found concerning working with LaTeX and Git was this, interesting replies there, but not enough for me and what I'm looking for. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297075/latex-git-bibliography

Comment: You can place a local copy of .sty and .cls files in the working directory. Upon compilation, these files will be used instead of those in the installation tree. However, depending on which packages or classes you have in mind, this would make your working directory quite large.

Comment: @JasperHabicht will try this out right away. If it's the case that those local *.sty and *.cls are used automatically without any tinkering, that sounds very handy and precisely what I'm looking for.

Comment: maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc

Comment: ... if you just need a reproducible environment, maybe have a look at https://github.com/islandoftex/texlive

Comment: Thank you, both of these look very interesting @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz! I'll have a look at the bundledoc as soon as my system manages to reconnect to CTAN.