# Setting up the texmf folder in MacTeX

Tags: mactex, texmf

I have the following instructions for Windows:

[image]

However, I am using Mac OS X with the latest version of MacTeX.

I already found this thread:

[How to make LaTeX see local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tree)

But I am not sure if this is similar to my case. Any ideas how I can perform these steps on a Mac OS X operating system?

Comment: The instructions you have a not just 'for Windows' but 'for MiKTeX', which does things a little differently to TeX Live (used by MacTeX). MacTeX automatically looks for a local tree in `~/Libary/texmf`: did you try adding stuff there?

Comment: If you don't have a local tree set up, I have a small app that will set one up for you: [Make local texmf](https://www.msu.edu/~amunn/latex/make-local-texmf.zip)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I add a .sty file to my MacTeX/TeXShop installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10256/2693)

Comment: Joseph Wright, the directory ~/Library/texmf does not exist (even when I show hidden directories), should I simply create this directory manually?

Comment: @Pietair Yes. I too had to manually create my `~/Library/texmf` folder.