# How to set TEXMFHOME so that it works

Tags: texlive, mac

I have installed Tex Live on OS X using the `install-tl` with the `-portable` option. (I can't use MacTeX because I don't have admin access on the particular machine.)

Having installed, I ran

```
tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME "~/texmf"
```

as suggested in this answer

[How to make LaTeX see local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30494/how-to-make-latex-see-local-texmf-tr)

and put stuff under

```
~/texmf/latex
```

but I get an error.

> ! LaTeX Error: File not
>   found.

```
kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME
```

returns

```
~/texmf
```

so I think it should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you put in `~/texmf/latex`? By default, TeX won't look for anything there. Probably, you needed `~/texmf/tex/latex`? For example, `mypackage.sty` would go in `~/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage/mypackage.sty`.

Comment: As cfr explained, your TEXMFHOME directory structure at (now) `~/texmf` must mimic the normal TDS, which means LaTeX stuff goes at `~/texmf/tex/latex`.  I'd do something like `mkdir ~/texmf/bibtex/{bib,bst} && mkdir ~/texmf/tex/latex` if you plan on using your local tree.

Comment: @jon Should probably note that this is ***not*** the local tree but the home/personal one. The local one is given in `TEXMFLOCAL`.

Comment: @cfr -- Indeed. Apparently I wrote the last sentence too carelessly. For clarity, the command `kpsewhich --var-value` can be completed by using `TEXMFHOME`, `TEXMFLOCAL`, and `TEXMFDIST` to learn about the 'home', 'local', and 'system' directories; meanwhile, `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF` will list all your 'texmf's in the order (I believe) that they will be searched.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note first that there is a difference between the *local* tree and your *home* tree. By default, they are in different places and are searched in different ways.

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

returns the current location of your personal tree.

However, this isn't enough. TeX looks in specific places for specific kinds of files. For example, it looks for `.sty`, `.cls` and `.tex` files in some directories but not others. Similarly for `.bib` and `bst` files and so on.

The easiest way to figure out where to put something is often to mimic the structure of the main distribution tree.

```
ls $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST)
```

shows the top level directory. `.sty` and `.cls` files are in sub-directories under `tex/latex/`, `.bib` files in sub-directories under `bibtex/bib/` and so on.

Another approach to to query the search path. For example

```
kpsewhich -show-path=bib
```

will tell me where BibTeX will look for `.bib` files.

```
kpsewhich -show-path=tex
```

will tell me where TeX will look for `.tex` files.

However, it is a bit less clear how to use this method to get the search path for `.sty` and `.cls` files.

```
kpsewhich -show-path=sty
```

returns an error. To figure out which values are acceptable, you can display a full list

```
kpsewhich -help-format
```

which, on my system, returns

```
kpathsea version 6.2.1

Recognized Kpathsea format names and their (abbreviations) and suffixes:
gf: gf  [variables: GFFONTS GLYPHFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/gf/$MAKETEX_MODE//]
pk: pk  [variables: PKFONTS TEXPKS GLYPHFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/pk/{$MAKETEX_MODE,modeless}//]
bitmap font (bitmapfont):  [variables: GLYPHFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts]
tfm: .tfm  [variables: TFMFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/tfm//]
afm: .afm  [variables: AFMFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/afm//:$OSFONTDIR//]
base: .base  [variables: MFBASES TEXMFINI]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/web2c{/$engine,}]
bib: .bib  [variables: BIBINPUTS TEXBIB]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/bibtex/bib//]
bst: .bst  [variables: BSTINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/bibtex/{bst,csf}//]
cnf: .cnf  [variables: TEXMFCNF]
  [original path (from compile-time paths.h) = {$SELFAUTOLOC,$SELFAUTOLOC/share/texmf-local/web2c,$SELFAUTOLOC/share/texmf-dist/web2c,$SELFAUTOLOC/share/texmf/web2c,$SELFAUTOLOC/texmf-local/web2c,$SELFAUTOLOC/texmf-dist/web2c,$SELFAUTOLOC/texmf/web2c,$SELFAUTODIR,$SELFAUTODIR/share/texmf-local/web2c,$SELFAUTODIR/share/texmf-dist/web2c,$SELFAUTODIR/share/texmf/web2c,$SELFAUTODIR/texmf-local/web2c,$SELFAUTODIR/texmf-dist/web2c,$SELFAUTODIR/texmf/web2c,$SELFAUTOGRANDPARENT/texmf-local/web2c,$SELFAUTOPARENT,$SELFAUTOPARENT/share/texmf-local/web2c,$SELFAUTOPARENT/share/texmf-dist/web2c,$SELFAUTOPARENT/share/texmf/web2c,$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-local/web2c,$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-dist/web2c,$SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf/web2c}]
ls-R: ls-R ls-r  [variables: TEXMFDBS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = {!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST,$TEXMFARCH}]
fmt: .fmt  [variables: TEXFORMATS TEXMFINI]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/web2c{/$engine,}]
map: .map  [variables: TEXFONTMAPS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/map/{$progname,pdftex,dvips,}//]
mem: .mem  [variables: MPMEMS TEXMFINI]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/web2c{/$engine,}]
mf: .mf  [variables: MFINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/metafont//:{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/source//]
mfpool: .pool  [variables: MFPOOL TEXMFINI]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = ${TEXPOOL}]
mft: .mft  [variables: MFTINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/mft//]
mp: .mp  [variables: MPINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/metapost//]
mppool: .pool  [variables: MPPOOL TEXMFINI]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = ${TEXPOOL}]
MetaPost support (mpsupport):  [variables: MPSUPPORT]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/metapost/support]
ocp: .ocp  [variables: OCPINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/omega/ocp//]
ofm: .ofm .tfm  [variables: OFMFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/{ofm,tfm}//]
opl: .opl  .pl  [variables: OPLFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/opl//]
otp: .otp  [variables: OTPINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/omega/otp//]
ovf: .ovf .vf  [variables: OVFFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/{ovf,vf}//]
ovp: .ovp  .vpl  [variables: OVPFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/ovp//]
graphic/figure:  .eps .epsi  [variables: TEXPICTS TEXINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/tex/{$progname,generic,}//]
tex: .tex  .sty .cls .fd .aux .bbl .def .clo .ldf  [variables: TEXINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/tex/{$progname,generic,}//]
TeX system documentation (doc):  [variables: TEXDOCS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = $TEXMF/doc//]
texpool: .pool  [variables: TEXPOOL TEXMFINI]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/web2c]
TeX system sources (source):  .dtx .ins  [variables: TEXSOURCES]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/source//]
PostScript header:  .pro  [variables: TEXPSHEADERS PSHEADERS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//]
Troff fonts (trofffont):  [variables: TRFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = /usr{/local,}/share/groff/{current/font,site-font}/devps]
type1 fonts: .pfa .pfb  [variables: T1FONTS T1INPUTS TEXFONTS TEXPSHEADERS PSHEADERS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/type1//:$OSFONTDIR//]
vf: .vf  [variables: VFFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/vf//]
dvips config (dvipsconfig):  [variables: TEXCONFIG]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = $TEXMF/dvips//]
ist: .ist  [variables: TEXINDEXSTYLE INDEXSTYLE]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/makeindex//]
truetype fonts: .ttf .ttc .TTF .TTC .dfont  [variables: TTFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/{truetype,opentype}//:$OSFONTDIR//]
type42 fonts: .t42 .T42  [variables: T42FONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/type42//]
web2c files (web2c):  [variables: WEB2C]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = $TEXMF/web2c]
other text files (othertext):  [variables: KPSEWHICHINPUTS]
  [original path (from compile-time paths.h) = .:$TEXMF/kpsewhich//]
other binary files (otherbin):  [variables: KPSEWHICHINPUTS]
  [original path (from compile-time paths.h) = .:$TEXMF/kpsewhich//]
misc fonts (miscfont):  [variables: MISCFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/misc//]
web: .web  .ch  [variables: WEBINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/web//]
cweb: .w .web  .ch  [variables: CWEBINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/cweb//]
enc files: .enc  [variables: ENCFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/enc//]
cmap files (cmap):  [variables: CMAPFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/cmap//]
subfont definition files: .sfd  [variables: SFDFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/sfd//]
opentype fonts: .otf  [variables: OPENTYPEFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/{opentype,truetype}//:$OSFONTDIR//]
pdftex config (pdftexconfig):  [variables: PDFTEXCONFIG]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/pdftex/{$progname,}//]
lig files: .lig  [variables: LIGFONTS TEXFONTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/lig//]
texmfscripts:  [variables: TEXMFSCRIPTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = $TEXMF/scripts/{$progname,$engine,}//]
lua: .lua .luatex .luc .luctex .texlua .texluc .tlu  [variables: LUAINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/scripts/{$progname,$engine,}/{lua,}//:$TEXMF/tex/{luatex,plain,generic,}//]
font feature files: .fea  [variables: FONTFEATURES]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/fea//]
cid maps: .cid .cidmap  [variables: FONTCIDMAPS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/fonts/cid//]
mlbib: .mlbib .bib  [variables: MLBIBINPUTS BIBINPUTS TEXBIB]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/bibtex/bib/{mlbib,}//]
mlbst: .mlbst .bst  [variables: MLBSTINPUTS BSTINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/bibtex/{mlbst,bst}//]
clua: .dll .so  [variables: CLUAINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$SELFAUTOLOC/lib/{$progname,$engine,}/lua//]
ris: .ris  [variables: RISINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/bibtex/ris//]
bltxml: .bltxml  [variables: BLTXMLINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/bibtex/bltxml//]

To see paths after expansion, use --show-path=FMT.

Email bug reports to tex-k@tug.org.
```

This is best used with `grep` else you may never find what you need:

```
kpsewhich -help-format | grep -1 sty
```

returns

```
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/tex/{$progname,generic,}//]
tex: .tex  .sty .cls .fd .aux .bbl .def .clo .ldf  [variables: TEXINPUTS]
  [original path (from texmf.cnf) = .:$TEXMF/tex/{$progname,generic,}//]
```

So we know that `.sty` and `.cls` files will be found in sub-directories under sub-directories such as `tex/latex/`, as well as `tex/generic/`.

It is usual to use a further sub-directory for files belonging to a package e.g. `tex/latex/fancyhdr/` or whatever. This tends to keep things a bit tidier and saner than they might otherwise be.