# How to get rid of last comma

Tags: comma-separated-list

I am using the following code to print a list of all characters that say something in a given scene of a play-script.

```
\newcommand\sceneroles[2][Roles]{%
  \def\scenename{#2}%
  \textbf{#1}:%
  \Bind{?id}{rdf:type}{rl:role}{%
    % \GetVal prints the variable name,
    % \GetValProperty extracts property from the name
    % Set the default left time
    % use the real at:left if it has been set
    \IfProperty{\GetVal{?id}}{is:playsin#2}{%
        \GetValProperty{?id}{rl:name}, %
    }{}%
  }%
}
```

the problem is, that I cannot get rid of the last comma.

what should be printed is:

`Roles: Romeo, Juliet`

what is printed:

`Roles: Romeo, Juliet,`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Should we look in every package to find out where `\GetValProperty` and `\Bind` are defined and guess how you get Romeo and Juliet out of thin air?

Comment: By the way, there's no trace of `\GetValProperty` in TeX Live files.

Comment: Sorry, it's rdfdef from this other question a few years ago: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473097/define-a-command-like-table-of-contents-but-for-attendees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this definition:

```
\newcommand\sceneroles[2][Roles]{%
  \def\scenename{#2}% Store scene names
  \def\namesep{\def\namesep{, }}% One cycle delay name separator
  \textbf{#1}:%
  \Bind{?id}{rdf:type}{rl:role}{%
    % \GetVal prints the variable name,
    % \GetValProperty extracts property from the name
    % Set the default left time
    % use the real at:left if it has been set
    \IfProperty{\GetVal{?id}}{is:playsin#2}{%
      \namesep\GetValProperty{?id}{rl:name}%
    }{}%
  }%
}
```

It uses a [cunning (La)TeX trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764).

Comment: What if the cycles are performed in a group?