# Add a specific document class created by a journal to the directory

Tags: installing, document-classes

I am writing my first document in the Texmaker program and I need to use the jfm (Journal of Fluid Mechanics) class, but I don't know how; even after reading some answers here and videos. I already downloaded the zip file with the document class, but I'm not sure where the sub-directory is and which files I need to place there. Could someone help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried copying the `.cls` file (or basically everything that was in the `.zip` archive) in the same folder than your `.tex` document?

Comment: I copied to the folder where tex was installed, now I copied there and doesn't give me the error anymore. I can start working now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Most common classes and packages files are copied (and thus installed) in your *TeX install tree* when you install a LaTeX distro (MikeTeX, TeXlive, MacTeX, etc.) on your OS. Thus, (La)TeX knows where to find relevant files when you compile your `.tex` document.

But in some cases (yours, with the `jfm` class), the class or package is not embedded in the TeX distro you installed. Since "installing" a class or a package is just copying its file (`.cls` or `.sty`, respectively) in a folder where (La)TeX will look for it, you have two possibilities (i.e. two loctation where (La)TeX will look for it):

- **Copy the `.cls` file in your local TeXmf tree** (hint for [TeXlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30494/64454), and for [MikeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/64454)). This will make the class/package available for each project you'll create.
- **Or copy the `.cls` file in the same folder than your `.tex` document**. It is the easiest, but you will have to repeat it for each new project.

Comment: It's better to install it in a `local` TeXMF root, not in the main (distribution) root. Under TeX Live, such a local root is created at installation, but under MiKTeX, you have to create one, and let MiKTeX know it (via `MiKTeX Settings (admin)`).

Comment: I’m sorry, but this is a *bad* answer (indeed, it would deserve a downvote): tampering with the installation tree is never a good idea; among other things, future updates will almost surely “hide” the added file, so that it won’t be found any longer.  Personal files should be stored either in the **local** texmf tree or in a user’s **personal** texmf tree, and actually the answer you are linking to speaks of the latter.  Under both of those tree, `.cls` and `.sty` file, in particular, should be placed inside `tex/latex/`, or a sub-(sub-…sub-)directory thereof.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti No need to be sorry, as it is factual. Anyway, thanks to your comment I've updated the answer accordingly.