# How to update biblatex in ubuntu

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to update biblatex, but I cannot succeed.

I'm following this guide from README file:

SEMI-AUTOMATIC INSTALLATION

1. Get the file biblatex-.tds.zip from

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/
2. Unpack the archive in the root directory of the local TeX
   installation tree, for example

   /usr/local/share/texmf/  [I put it in this folder]

   or

   /usr/share/texmf-local/

   or

   C:\Local TeX Files\
3. Update the file hash tables (also known as the file name
   database).

   On teTeX and TeX Live systems, run texhash as root ('sudo
   texhash'). On MiKTeX, run 'initexmf --update-fndb' in a command
   window or use the 'Refresh FNDB' button of the MiKTeX Options
   window.

But I'm continuously receiving this message on Texstudio:

Package biblatex Error: Style 'abnt-numeric' not found. \RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}

Does anybody knows how to resolve it?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, package texlive-full

Comment: That is probably because you haven't installed `biblatex-abnt`. It has not been around that long. Get it from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt unpack it and drop it in your local tree (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30494/35864).

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much! I thought it would come with biblatex.

Comment: If you want an up-to-date system on which you can install all CTAN packages easily, you might want to consider installing a 'vanilla TeX live' instead of the repository version (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `biblatex-abnt` package separately. If you can't install packages via your TeX distribution (as is the case with the repository version of TeX live on Ubuntu), you need to install the package manually.

Get it from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt and unpack it into your local TeX tree.