# Setting path to bst files installed by TexLive

Tags: bibtex, texlive, revtex

I installed TexLive 2013 from the installer provided at CTAN on Ubuntu Linux.
I have been able to use latex and pdflatex commands so far, but I have a problem with bibtex. Is there any setting (such as exporting an environmental variable) that I needed to make to let bibtex know where `.bst` files are?

The bibtex command does not seem to recognize the `.bst` files stored under 
`texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/revtex/`, 
`texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/natbib/`, etc.

However, the `.bst` files under 
`texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/`
seem to be recognized.

The style file I actually want to use is
`texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/revtex/aipnum4-1.bst`.
If I do 
`$ kpsewhich aipnum4-1.bst`
I get nothing.

I didn't change anything on the tex system after I installed the TexLive 2013. I didn't add a file manually, or I didn't update the TexLive.

---

Edit

According to the comment, I am adding a small example. The following set of `sample.tex` and `fa.bib` can be compiled to a PDF with pdflatex and bibtex. The `plain.bst` is under `texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/`.
If I change `\bibliographystyle` to `aipnum4-1` or  the other styles commented out, the reference section is not produced, and the citation is noted by a question mark.

`sample.tex`

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}

This is the minimum story I heard from the king of Elephants. \cite{pa}

\bibliography{fa.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
% .. works
%\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}
% .. does not work
%\bibliographystyle{siam}
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

`fa.bib`

```
@Article{pa,
  author =   {Elegant Elephant},
  title =    {Eggs of Elephants are Elegant},
  journal =  {Elite Elephants},
  year =     {2399},
  volume =   3,
  pages =    447,
}
```

---

Edit 2

I found that my setting of `PATH` environmental variable (as well as `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH`) was inappropriate. I had set them in `/etc/profile` as

```
INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
```

I corrected it to

```
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
```

My Ubuntu package manager seems to have installed its own tex system under `/usr/share/texlive/` and `/usr/share/texmf/`, probably because another package depends on the tex package.

With the first, wrong setting of `PATH`, ubuntu installation of tex-related executables had precedence over my installation of texlive 2013 directly from CTAN. For example, `kpsewhich` at `/usr/bin/kpsewhich`
was used instead of `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich`.
As a result, when I did

```
kpsewhich plain.bst
```

I got

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/plain.bst
```

which was installed by ubuntu's tex package. This package installed only `bibtex/bst/base/` but not `bibtex/bst/revtex/` or other bst directories, 
`kpsewhich aipnum4-1.bst` resulted in empty string.

Now, with the corrected PATH setting,

```
kpsewhich aipnum4-1.bst
```

returns

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/revtex/aipnum4-1.bst
```

The above sample tex file can be compiled to a PDF with any of the bst files listed in the comment.

It looks that ubuntu's tex package did not install `pdflatex`, and I had used 
`/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex` happily so far.

I realized my mistake while reading this answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273893/62461

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: did you install the `.bst` files for `revtex` and `natbib` separately from the main installation?  if so, you have to update the database.  how to do that is shown in this question: [How to update biblatex in ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367784/579).

Comment: All these `.bst` came with TexLive, and I didn't do any manual installation.